# Automation error on VBA using an imported custom C# class

Tags: c#, .net, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to use a class on Access VBA 7.0 which implements an Interface I made and I'm still getting "Automation error" even after adding the usual headers.

DropBox.cs

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("E2F07CD4-CE73-4102-B35D-119362624C47")]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ICloudFileProvider))]
[ProgId("CloudFiles.dll")]
public class DropBox : ICloudFileProvider
{
    public DropBox()
    {
        ConectaDropbox("TokenLongChicken");
    }
    public DropBox(string tokenUsuario)
    {  //This was the original and good constructor. I know I can't use constructors with arguments on VBA. Just keeping it to compile with Test
        ConectaDropbox(tokenUsuario);
    }
    public void ConectaDropbox(string tokenUsuario)
    {
    }
    // This method and others come implemented from an interface (ICloudFileProvider)
    public string SubirArchivo(string rutaLocal, string carpetaCloud, Tipos.TipoSobreescritura tipoSobreescritura)
    {
    }
```

This didn't work, so I saw I have to "create" a header for the Interface and I did it on the Interface itself. I'm still getting the error, so on the DropBox class, I added another header "enumerating" the methods I'm using on this class (which has no sense, but I've read another questions on SO which concretes you have to do so).

So I added this at the end of the DropBox class, noting it is as well on the ICloudFileProvider Interface (the real one).

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("E2F11CD4-CE73-4102-B35D-119362624C47")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IExposedClass
{
    void DropBox();
    void DropBox(string tokenUsuario);
    void ConectaDropbox(string tokenUsuario);
    string SubirArchivo(string rutaLocal, string carpetaCloud, Tipos.TipoSobreescritura tipoSobreescritura);
    decimal ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes);
    void Descargar(string link, string carpetaLocal);
    string GenerarLink(string rutaCloud);
    void EliminarArchivo(string link);
}
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong but I'm kind of lost in this DLL and TLB hell. This project just works fine on C# but I need to integrate it on VBA and I see no examples with projects which uses real interfaces. I'm not really sure if the "InterfaceIsIUnkown" I add at the end of the DropBox class makes any sense, but I saw it on every example I found on the Internet (but none of them used a real Interface).

Could anybody help? Thanks.

P.S: yes, I perform the RegAsm.exe export to .TLB and then I add it to my Access, with no export errors apparently.

Comment: Looks like it was something related with the project properties and the headers (everything was kind of duplicated). I concreted to use the "make assembly-COM visible" and I guess that adding those header mixed everything up. Thanks for all anyway.